# removing white space from a meta tag

Tags: html, facebook, meta

I need a person to help me remove the whitespace from this meta tag

```
 <meta  property="og:image" content="<?php echo'<img src="../photo/'.$row['image1'].'" >';?>">
```

Comment: which whitespace? the "meta__"? probably just in your code

Comment: There's a white space directly after 'meta'. There's also another at the end of the image tag. This what you're looking for?

Comment: Can you please describe in further details what you mean or what is wrong?